# Cómo agrupar datos dentro de un loop en R

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio, r-dplyr

Tengo el dataset descargado de google mobility report y la idea es procesarlo y agruparlo por países y por mes para poder tener un resumen más escueto. Cuando hago un `for` que recorra todas las variantes que hay de movilidad y lo exporto a excel, los valores aparecen vacíos o los valores son todos iguales. Dejo el script para vuestra consideración.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)
library(writexl)

Global_Mobility_Report <- read.csv("C:/Global_Mobility_Report.csv")
View(Global_Mobility_Report)

Global_Mobility_Report$date <- as.Date(Global_Mobility_Report$date)                                     
Global_Mobility_Report$mes <- month(Global_Mobility_Report$date)

names <- colnames(Global_Mobility_Report)

for (i in 9:14) {
  
  data = paste("Global_Mobility_Report$", names[i], sep = "")
  
  df <- Global_Mobility_Report %>%
    group_by(mes, country_region) %>% 
    summarise(value_mean = mean(data, na.rm = TRUE))
  
  dataset <- df %>% 
    spread(mes, value_mean)
  nombre = paste(names[i], ".xlsx")
  
  write_xlsx(dataset,nombre)
  
}
```

El resultado que espero es un excel que contenga en la primera fila los meses, en la primera columna los países. Que tenga una solapa por variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí hay lo que creo que es una solución, aunque no tengo del todo claro el problema. De todos modos podría ayudarte a resolverlo o a entenderlo mejor.

## Librerías:

```
library(readr)
library(tidyverse) # para dplyr y purr, se podrían cargar por separado
library(lubridate) # para month


gmr <- read_csv("Global_Mobility_Report.csv", 
                col_types = cols(date = col_datetime(format = "%Y-%m-%d"))) #Defino aquí como fecha a date, ya lo lee así
```

## Sumario de medias

En lugar de usar un bucle y posiciones de columna fijas (9:14) uso `summarise(across())` e indico sobre qué columnas aprovechando que las que interesan terminan todas en el mismo sufijo: "from_baseline". Uso el argumento `na.rm = TRUE` en `mean` porque si hay algún missing la función regresa `NA`.

```
gmr %>% 
  mutate(mes = month(date)) %>% 
  group_by(country_region, mes) %>% 
  summarise(across(ends_with("from_baseline"),  
            mean, na.rm = TRUE)) -> medias_tidy
```

Por la forma en que trabajo el formato del objeto `medias_tidy`  me parece que es el formato final: cada fila es una observación (media por país y mes) y cada columna es una variable (tipo de actividad). Sin embargo por el `spread` entiendo que buscas que cada columna sea un combinación mes/variable y cada fila un país. Si no es así podrías definir mejor los resultados esperados en la pregunta, siempre puedes editarla.

## Lista de países

Como creo que quieres un excel para cada país comienzo por convertir a ese data.frame en una lista, en la que cada elemento es un país. Con esto me adelanto al paso siguiente que será escribir un archivo por país. El problema es que como tengo una lista necesitaré un iterador para hacer las operaciones dentro de esa lista. En este caso uso `map()`, en el que se puede declarar una función anónima usando el símbolo `~`, en lugar de usar `function(x) {}`. Usando `map()` pivoteo los datos para lograr que cada columna sea una combinación de mes y variable. Especifico el nombre de esas columnas pegando el mes y el value con `names_glue`.

> pivot_wider >> spread

Obtengo una lista en la que cada elemento es un data.frame con una sola fila. ¿Buscas eso?

```
split(medias_tidy, medias_tidy$country_region) %>% 
  map(~pivot_wider(.x, 
                   names_from  = mes, 
                   values_from = ends_with("from_baseline"), 
                   names_glue  = "{mes}_{.value}")) -> lista_ancha_por_pais
```

## Escribir los archivos

Para escribirlo al disco uso `purr::iwalk()`, que es de la misma familia de `map()`, pero en lugar de generar una lista genera solamente el side effect, en este caso escribir el archivo. Uso la versión `iwalk()` que me permite iterar simultaneamente sobre una lista (argumento .x) y sobre los nombres de la lista (argumento .y). Paso sobre la lista anterior y para cada elemento escribo un archivo y le doy como nombre el nombre del elemento en la lista (el país) y la extención .csv. En este test escribo .csv en lugar de .xlsx porque no tengo instalada la libería que lo contiene, pero es más o menos lo mismo.

```
iwalk(lista_ancha_por_pais[1:2], 
      ~write_csv(.x, 
                 path = paste0(.y, ".csv"))
      )
```

Ojalá te sirva de algo, si no resuelve indícalo en un comentario o, mejor aún, especifica mejor tu pregunta. Entiendo que aplicar iteradores y manejar listas tiene una curva de aprendizaje empinada, pero la programación funcional es muy potente y al crear los objetos paso a paso es muchísimo más fácil ir identificar errores vs. hacerlo dentro de un bucle.

## Todo el código junto:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
gmr <- read_csv("Global_Mobility_Report.csv", 
                                   col_types = cols(date = col_datetime(format = "%Y-%m-%d")))

gmr %>% 
  mutate(mes = month(date)) %>% 
  group_by(country_region, mes) %>% 
  summarise(across(ends_with("from_baseline"),  
            mean, na.rm = TRUE)) -> medias_tidy

split(medias_tidy, medias_tidy$country_region) %>% 
  map(~pivot_wider(.x, 
                   names_from =mes, 
                   values_from = ends_with("from_baseline"), 
                   names_glue = "{mes}_{.value}")) -> lista_ancha_por_pais

iwalk(lista_ancha_por_pais[1:2], 
      ~write_csv(.x, 
                 path = paste0(.y, ".csv"))
      )
```

## Actualización

A partir de un comentario de @kev va una solución al problema mejor especificado.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
gmr <- read_csv("Global_Mobility_Report.csv", 
                col_types = cols(date = col_datetime(format = "%Y-%m-%d")))

gmr %>% 
  mutate(mes = month(date)) %>% 
  group_by(country_region, mes) %>% 
  summarise(across(ends_with("from_baseline"),  
                   mean, na.rm = TRUE)) -> medias_tidy

medias_tidy %>% 
# Paso a formato largo para después poder separar por variable
  pivot_longer(cols = retail_and_recreation_percent_change_from_baseline:residential_percent_change_from_baseline, 
               names_to = "variable", 
               values_to = "valor") %>%
  split(.$variable) %>% 
# Dentro de cada elemento de la lista (variables) paso a formato ancho, para que cada mes sea una columna
  map(~pivot_wider(.x, names_from = mes, values_from = valor)) -> lista_variables_meses

library(openxlsx) #Esto es una maravilla que escribe xlsx sin la dependencia de Rjava que tienen otras librerías


write.xlsx(lista_variables_meses, file = "test_excel.xlsx") #Si le pasas una lista de data.frame por defectos hace una hoja nombrada por cada df
```

Comment: Hola @mpaladino, esta muy bien tu script pero lo que busco es que en un excel esten los países por fila y los meses por columna, un excel para cada variable (sería óptimo tener un excel donde cada solapa sea una variable)

Comment: Hola @kev, hay una respuesta actualizada que hace lo que buscas. Sería muy bueno que editaras la pregunta e incluyeras ahí los resultados esperados, tal como están en este comentario. De ese modo otras personas con el mismo problema podrían encontrar más fácilmente una solución.

Comment: por qué el excel que sale del resultado me tira los meses 1,2,3,4,5,7,8,6 y no 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 ?

Comment: Porque pivot_wider ordena las columnas por orden de aparición de las categorías y para Afganistán falta la observación del mes 6, entonces aparece recién en Angola y el puntero ya había pasado por el 10. Se arregla usando arrange(mes) antes de armar la lista (el split)